# How do I add non dependent libraries from my workspace in to a subdirectory of the output folder during compile?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-crates

I have been working on a software than needs to dynamically load libraries at runtime from a specific folder in Rust 1.72.1. For this am experimenting with ways to test this functionality for CI, but I am running into the problem that I have not been successful at changing the directory to which to compile the libraries while *not* changing the target directory for the main application.

Example workspace layout:

```
workspace_root
├── Cargo.toml
├── lib_a
│  ├── Cargo.toml
│  └── src
│     └── lib.rs
├── lib_b
│  ├── Cargo.toml
│  └── src
│     └── lib.rs
├── main_program
│  ├── Cargo.toml
│  └── src
│     └── main.rs
└── master_lib
   ├── Cargo.toml
   └── src
      └── lib.rs
```

`lib_a` and `lib_b` do have `master_lib` as a dependency, but not the other way around and main program only depends on `master_lib`.
What I would want this to result in is the following:

```
target
├── libraries
│  ├── lib_a.dll
│  └── lib_b.dll
└── main_program.exe
```

I have tried using the build.rs functionality of cargo but the only way I found to do it in there is to use `std::process::command` to invoke cargo to compile each library resulting in the need to recompile `master_lib` for every library which seems redundant.

I am also aware of the cargo_make plugin but I have not ried it as I suspect it will have the same problem as the `build.rs` in that it will need to recompile `master_lib` for every library.

TL;DR: Is there a way to define the compile output folder for each member of a workspace individually?

Comment: Annoying workaround, but could you use different targets for each member? I found [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/7004) potentially describing how to compile members with different targets. If that's an acceptable workaround, you could have isolated targets for isolated compilations, keeping all of the tidbits separated.

Comment: During my research i did also stumble over the idea of per crate targets as well. It might work for the example i have described but for the final software we are talking about 30+ libraries as a lower estimate.